# How to recalculate TCP data checksum in skbuff

Tags: c++, linux, networking, tcp, kernel

Using my netfilter i change data of incoming packets using this code:

```
unsigned int hook_func_in(unsigned int hooknum, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct net_device *in, const struct net_device *out, int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *)) 
{
    struct iphdr *ip = 0;
    struct tcphdr *tcp = 0;
    unsigned char *user_data = 0; 
    unsigned char *tail = 0;
    int datasize =0;

    if ( skb )
    {
        ip = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);
        if (ip && ip->protocol == IPPROTO_TCP)
        {
            skb_set_transport_header(skb, ip->ihl * 4);
            tcp = (struct tcphdr *)skb_transport_header(skb);

            if ( tcp && tcp->dest == htons(63947))
            {               
                if (tcp->syn)
                {
                    printk ( "Connect %d\r\n", ip->saddr);
                }
                else if (tcp->fin || tcp->rst)
                {
                    printk ("Disconnect %d\r\n", ip->saddr);
                }
                else
                {
                    user_data = (unsigned char *)((unsigned char *)tcp + (tcp->doff * 4));
                    tail = skb_tail_pointer(skb);
                    if( user_data && tail )
                    {
                        datasize = (int)((long)tail-(long)user_data);
                        if( datasize > 0 )
                        {
                            ModifyData((unsigned char*)user_data, (unsigned char*)user_data, datasize);
                            // function above changes all data, but not resizes
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return NF_ACCEPT;
}
```

Function `ModifyData` changes all bytes in data but don't change size of data. How now i should recalculate tcp checksum? I know about function `tcp_check_send` but i'm not sure it situable for incoming packets.
Maybe after changing data i should change something too?

I need this because if i change data without recalculating the same packet will be received again several times and then connection will be terminated

Comment: [RFC 1071, Computing the Internet Checksum](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1071) explains how to calculate a TCP checksum.